# Access to CSS rules from JavaScript even to unknown CSS syntax or unsupported HTML element of browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, polyfills

Is it possible to get CSS rules that might be applied to element say according to HTML5/CSS3 even if browser isn't supported HTML element or CSS pseudo-class?

For example I like [HTML5 constraint validation attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) and wonder is it possible to create polyfills for old browser that emulate HTML5 behavior.

More strictly if we have any modern HTML5:

```
<section><input required type="email"></section>
```

and modern CSS3+:

```
section input:invalid { border-radius: 3px; }
input[type="email"] {
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

and browser have incomplete or buggy support of HTML5/CSS3 and limited to ECMA 3.0 JS support with some ancient DOM levels is it possible:

- to get *section -> input* DOM structure in JS
- to known that there are CSS rule applied to *input* with unknown property *border-radius*
- to browser highlight *background: yellow* even if *type* is unknown attribute?

I heard that browser work with [forward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility) which mean to ignore unknown elements. I afraid that this lead to removing unknown CSS/HTML from DOM, or at list JS engine may not access via DOM API to these parts.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but this sounds like most of it already exists in Modernizr.

Comment: To my knowledge Modernizr detect capabilities but don't try to access to actual .html/.css file content that made by developers. I wander is it possible to access to that content even if some parts are unsupported by browser due to it age or due to very novelty of some w3c specs.

Comment: It is "wonder" not "wander" please stop the maddness

Comment: Try inspecting element in an older browser, if it does not show, you cannot modify it.